# How to force inline divs to stay on same line?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a three-column layout. I'd like the width of the left and right columns to be only as wide as their children content. I'd like the center column to expand to fill the remaining space.

I'm trying the following (overview, jsfiddle link included below):

```
#colLeft {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#colCenter {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  overflow: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#colRight {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
  <div id="colLeft">left</div>
  <div id="colCenter">Some really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.</div>
  <div id="colRight">right</div>
</div>
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5kszQ/

but the center column pushes the right column below it when its content is too long. I'd like all three columns to be inline, and have the center column shrink as necessary. This is what the above is giving me:

[image]

instead I would like:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Comment: is any of the widths fixed

Comment: None of the widths are fixed.

Comment: you must set max-width each div. Remove white-space attr then add word-break:break-all;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are open for some HTML changes, then this should give you exactly what you want:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100%">  
  <div id="colLeft">left</div>
  <div id="colwrap">
      <div id="colRight">right</div>
      <div id="colCenter">Some really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

and css to be:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#parent {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 48px;
}
#colLeft {
  background-color: #ff8b8b;
  height: 48px;
  float: left;
}
#colwrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: orange;      
}
#colCenter {
  height: 48px;  
}
#colRight {
  background-color: #c3d0ff;
  height: 48px;
  float: right;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gajbhiye/ZX97K/ Hope that helps.

Comment: Why are you placing a "#" instead of a dot "."?

Comment: @DaniSpringer.com "#" is the [css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for an id, while "." is the class selector

Comment: Why use one over the other?

Comment: id is used to target a specific element while class can be used to target a group of elements

Comment: ID should only be used once on the page whereas it is ok to use class throughout the webpage to target multiple elements for which you want the same styles.

Answer (score 25):

Here's one method using `inline-block` for the left and middle and `position:absolute` for the right element.

[image: Example]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/NMN5L/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
    <div id="colLeft">left</div><!--
    --><div id="colCenter">Some really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.</div>
    <div id="colRight">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#parent {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 48px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#colLeft {
    background-color: #ff8b8b;
    height: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#colCenter {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#colRight {
    background-color: #c3d0ff;
    height: 48px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Since it relys on `inline-block`, there is a comment in between the `<div>`s to get rid of the spacing illustrated in this image:

[image: Ugly spacing]

### text-overflow:ellipsis

To achieve this when using `text-overflow:ellipsis` you may need to fallback on JavaScript, here is a possible solution ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/NMN5L/4/)).

[image: Ellipsis using JavaScript]

```
window.onresize = updateDimensions;

function updateDimensions() {
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    var left = document.getElementById('colLeft');
    var right = document.getElementById('colRight');
    var middle = document.getElementById('colCenter');

    middle.style.width = (parent.offsetWidth - right.offsetWidth - left.offsetWidth)  + 'px';
}
```

Comment: To fix the whitespace between inline-block elements, you can set the font size in the parent container to 0, and then redeclare the desired font size in the children :)

Comment: There are a few different workarounds, I think they all suck to be honest :P

Comment: With this method, then using "text-overflow: ellipsis" on colCenter won't work, right? If I understand correctly, part of colCenter is sitting underneath colRight in z-order, right? Thanks

Comment: Yep. The issue with using inline-block in this case is that the content container (three of them in this case) is and only is as wide as its content goes - therefore the width does not collapse properly when the viewport gets too narrow: overflow, text-overflow will not help, unless a minimum-width is set, which has to be somewhat calculated.  I can think of a JS + CSS combo solution, but not a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 3):

Fool the browser with saying that it all fits just well on a single line by adding some large margins to the center and right elements, and compensate for that with relative positioning. See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/5kszQ/5/)**.

Markup: remains intact.

Style:

```
#parent {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#colLeft {
  background-color: #ff8b8b;
  height: 48px;
  float: left;
}
#colCenter {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 48px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -2000px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2000px;
}
#colRight {
  background-color: #c3d0ff;
  height: 48px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -2000px;
  position: relative;
  left: -2000px;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Also, if the right column is of constant width, there's a nice way to make the overflow of the middle column nice: add left padding and put a gradient that soon goes from fully transparent to fully opaque in the background of colRight. http://jsfiddle.net/a52fm2am/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```css
#parent {
  word-break: break-all;
}

#colLeft {
  float: left;
  max-width: 5%;
}

#colCenter {
  float: left;
  max-width: 90%;
}

#colRight {
  float: right;
  max-width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
  <div id="colLeft">leftawefawefawefawef</div>
  <div id="colCenter">Some really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center.
    Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center. Some really long text in the
    center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome
    really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjlSome really long text in the center.
    Some really long text in the center.khjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjhkjhklkjl</div>
  <div id="colRight">rightaewfaewfawefawef</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the combination of setting of DIV: display, float and position, I have made  three child DIVs staying on one line.

Parent DIV: display:inlin-block
First two child DIVs:float: left;
Right child DIV:float:right; display:inline; position:absolute;

```css
.parent {
           width:100%;
            margin: 0 auto 10;
            clear:both; 
            margin-top:3px;
            display:inline-block;
            padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0;
        }
        .colLeft {
          float: left; 
          margin: 5px auto;
        }
        .colCenter {
          float:left; 
         position:relative;
          width:85%;
          margin: 5px auto 5px 5px;
        }
        .colRight {
           float: right;            
           display: inline; 
           position:absolute;
           margin-left: 2px;
        }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="colLeft">[0002]</div>
      <div class="colCenter">Very long text. Input the paragraph which describes the technical field here.Input the paragraph which describes the technical field here.Input the paragraph which describes the technical field here.Input the paragraph which describes the technical field here.Input the paragraph which describes the technical field here.Input the paragraph which describes the technical field here.</div>
      <div class="colRight"><b>*Note:123</b></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just place child divs into the table cells, while the table into parent div. No styling will be needed

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 100%">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><div id="colLeft">left</div></td>
   <td><div id="colCenter">Some really long text in the center. Some really long text in the center.</div></td>
   <td><div id="colRight">right</div></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind the question age is "7+ years"; thus provide versioning for which your solution applies. End of Review.