# Force divs on same line with expanded text

Tags: html, css

I need this this behavior :

```
[Short title text.txt []]
[Little longer title text.txt []]
[Longer title text with text text text ...[]]
[Longer title text with text tex ...[icon 1]]
[Longer title text with  ...[icon 1, icon 2]]
[Short title text.txt [icon 1, icon 2]]
```

- Dynamic length of title
- Dynamic number of end icons
- Everytime when text overflow add '...'

Purpose is, that there is title of file, when title is too long, add '...' on end, on end of title can be icon indicators (multiple, currently 0-2) which must be on end of text, not on end of line.

Example how it should look like : https://jsfiddle.net/s7nLe6cs/

I think that is maybe similar like this, but any of solution was not applicable for this : 
[How to force inline divs to stay on same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445164/how-to-force-inline-divs-to-stay-on-same-line)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are they divs? Use inline block. Have a fiddle for us?

Comment: Inline Block I tried, but I could not achieve this behavior, in moment I'll send fiddle

Comment: I hope, that will be more apparent https://jsfiddle.net/kjkxk0tg/ all should be on same line

Comment: Solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132028/css-how-to-force-divs-side-by-side-with-text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

If the content is the problem, then do this:

```css
.class-to-force-inline {
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      max-width: 50%; /* Whatever works here, I'm assuming two blocks with no padding/margin */
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0; padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class='class-to-force-inline'>
      Some super long text that just continues on forever and ever and ever.
    </div>
    <div class='class-to-force-inline'>
      Some shorter text.
    </div>
```

That's what's needed to get your text to overflow with ellipsis.

Comment: thanks for reply, problem is with dynamic width of text based od text length on which end must be container for multiple icons which must be on end of text, but with longer text container must be fixed on end of line

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of that comment.  What is it you need done?

Comment: I just create simple example of wrong behavior here https://jsfiddle.net/kjkxk0tg/

Comment: sorry, probably wrong described, this is how it should looks like : https://jsfiddle.net/s7nLe6cs/