# CSS How to force DIVs side by side with text overflow?

Tags: html, css

I need force 2 divs side by side as it below in example :

```
#colwrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: orange;
    width:300px;
}
#colLeft {
  height: 48px;  
  white-space: nowrap;    
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#colRight {
  background-color: #c3d0ff;
  height: 48px;
  float: right;
}


//This is cool
<div id="colwrap">
    <div id="colRight">icon1, icon2</div>
    <div id="colLeft">Really long long long name of file.txt</div>  
</div>

<br>

//But this is wrong : 

<div id="colwrap">
    <div id="colRight">icon1, icon2</div>
    <div id="colLeft">Short name of file.txt</div>  
</div>

//It should look like this, when text is shorter :

<div id="colwrap">
    <div id="colLeft" style="float:left;">Short name of file.txt</div> 
    <div id="colRight" style="float:left">icon1, icon2</div> 
</div>
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2jno80ba/

!There is div contains name of file, on every end of file must be container for multiple icons, when text is larger, then container is fixed on end.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMNZu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use flex-box to achieve this.
check this pen out:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOExbb

I just modified your css a bit:

```
#colwrap{
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
#colLeft {
  height: 48px;  
  white-space: nowrap;    
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#colRight {
  order:2;
  background-color: #c3d0ff;
  height: 48px;
  float: right;
}
```

and here is a [guide to flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

set the width of your divs as auto like `#colleft{width:auto;}`
https://jsfiddle.net/3v5jtcck/3/

Comment: Here is created new fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3v5jtcck/ but it is still same, please can you edited my code? I am really desperate, because I dealt with it for whole yesterday