# Bootstrap input group line break formatting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I have a bunch of rows with a check box and a label taking up 2 column spaces. Some of the labels are longer then others so when you resize the browser or are viewing on a mobile device the columns with longer labels will collapse to a second row and the shorter ones stay beside their check box. It looks like crap.

HTML:

```
<div class = "row">
<div class="col-lg-2"> 
   <div class="input-group">
   <input type="checkbox">
        Small Label
   </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2"> 
   <div class="input-group">
   <input type="checkbox">
        Big Label that collapses first
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make it so that if one of them collapses then the whole row does?

Even better would be to have a dynamic font that worked like an image and just grew and shrank taking up a maximum of 100% as necessary to not cause a collapse at all.  I could just use images but I have a lot of these these labels and it will take forever to make an image for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom CSS to your bootstrap style and define some simple CSS rules as you would like to force the style to behave...

**CSS Example:**

```
.input-group {
  display: inline;
}
```

I think the right HTML element for this is a *list*.. 
although, If you are going to edit the CSS... It's good to know that you can add a custom css file to your project and use a CSS class with your bootstrap style like this:

**CSS:**

```
.checkbox-inline {
  display: inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox">
    Small Label
</div>
```

There are many possible answers...
maybe, you will also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445164/how-to-force-inline-divs-to-stay-on-same-line) useful.

Comment: I used a label tag and had to move the checkbox-inline class to my label tag for this to work for me. Thank you for the lead.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap provides four classes for different screen :

1. *xs* for extra small
2. *sm* for small
3. *md* for medium
4. *lg* for large screen

In your following code should work, you can customize as per your screen needs :

```
<div class = "row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2"> 
     <div class="input-group">
       <input type="checkbox">
         Small Label
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-2"> 
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="checkbox">
          Big Label that collapses first
      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I ended up using a combination of this answer and the one below it so now as it collapses it goes from size 2 columns with 6 items to size 4 columns with 3 items. Everything lines up nice now looks good.