# @Html.DisplayFor div is bringing it to next line when its not needed

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I went through this forum for this problem. But none of the answers solved my problem. Hence I am asking a new question.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter Area</button>
<label id="areaText">@LanguagesFacade.GetValue(DictionaryKey.Area):</label>
<div id="totalAreaText">
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TotalArea)
</div>
```

It is displayed as below:

[image]

I want all of them in one line. But DisplayFor div goes to new line irrespective of any changes I tried([How to force inline divs to stay on same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445164/how-to-force-inline-divs-to-stay-on-same-line)). I added colwrap class to ProjectMain.css and enclosed these four elements under a div by giving id as colwrap, but I saw no change.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Well, `<div>` elements are by default blocks. Maybe try `<span>` instead

Comment: Did you use `display: inline;` on the div

Comment: Thank you so much @Phil. it fixed the problem.

Comment: How come you didn't know that

Comment: @MarkPerera: I am new to asp.net and web application. Hence I didnt know. :'(