# height: auto does not work on <li> elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, html-lists

I've been trying to fix this layout problem for an hour or so with no luck. I simply want my `li` to expand to match the height of its contents, so that `margin-bottom` will work correctly. Here's my code (note: this is just a draft, so the relevant CSS is mixed in via `style` attributes):

```
<!-- This uses ASP.NET markup syntax but should still be legible to anyone -->
<h2>Related</h2>
    <ul class="list-unstyled owner-list">
        @foreach (var package in Model.RecommendedPackages)
        {
            <li style="position: relative; word-break: break-all; height: auto;">
                <a href="@Url.Package(package.Id)" title="@package.Id" target="_blank">
                    <img class="owner-image" aria-hidden="true" alt="" width="32" height="32"
                        src="@(PackageHelper.ShouldRenderUrl(package.IconUrl) ? package.IconUrl : Url.Absolute("~/Content/gallery/img/default-package-icon.svg"))"
                        @ViewHelpers.ImageFallback(Url.Absolute("~/Content/gallery/img/default-package-icon-256x256.png"))
                        />
                </a>
                <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute;">
                    <a href="@Url.Package(package.Id)" title="@package.Id" target="_blank" style="word-wrap: break-word;">@package.Id</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Here are the dimensions of the `div` inside the `li`:

[image]

Here are the dimensions of the `li`, which is clearly shorter than its child `div`:

[image]

I tried using `height: auto;` to fix this (as you can see in the picture) but it didn't work. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Where's the rest of the CSS? Are the `li` inside a grid or flexbox? I mean, it's obviously inside an `ol` or `ul`, but IIRC I got strange behaviours when they were put inside grids or some how made flex

Comment: @flen I put a `<ul>` element in the code (2nd line). You can see the whole thing here: https://github.com/jamesqo/NuGetGallery/blob/1d6175189cb68f85709e60055f68726db3d7532a/src/NuGetGallery/Views/Packages/DisplayPackage.cshtml#L484

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have an absolutely positioned element inside of a relatively positioned element. When you have an absolutely positioned element, it doesn't take up any visual space inside the containing non-statically positioned element.

An absolute element is an element positioned relative to it's nearest non-static ancestor.

So, if you have a fixed, relative, sticky, or another absolute element ancestor (outer element), the inner element won't take up any space there.

The li element gets the 32 px height from the image inside, since li will automatically be the height of the contents, and additionally, it is explicitly (and unnecessarily) set to auto.

What you describe as the desired affect is the default. The height of the outer element will automatically fit the contents. The solution is to either put no position, and that will default or explicitly set position to a attribute that does take up space in its ancestors (static, relative, etc.).

Comment: AHA so that's why! I can't believe I repeatedly overlooked that. Thanks for your help, but I have another question. I put `position: absolute;` there following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445314/4077294) which told me to do that so that the anchor text would appear to the right of the image instead of on a new line. Is there any way I can have the `li` behave properly and still have the text appear on the same line?

Comment: the most important word you missed here is that the element is taken out of the flow and that's its height has no impact

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know. I don't know how to approach a different problem without using `position: absolute;` though.

Comment: I didn't use flow, because position and its attributes has a specific meaning. I am trying to be careful not to confuse concepts.

Comment: I edited my answer to better address your desired outcome.

Comment: Re: "I know. I don't know how to approach a different problem without using position: absolute; though."Absolute positioning is rarely needed for anything in a static structured document. With the exception of "sticky" because of support, absolute is least often needed. It's used for positioning stuff outside the document, like tool tips, modals, etc.. These aren't so much an answer as they are an opinionated tip: you probably don't need so many layers of html, a common problem in html is that it's too deeply nested - this makes it hard to manage, reuse, read, and style.