# How to have force divs to stay on the same line without using position: absolute?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I'm trying to have an image element side-by-side with an anchor element inside a `li`. If the text of the anchor element is very long, it should wrap to a new line and start at the same horizontal offset as the first line of the anchor.

My first try:

```
<h2>Related</h2>
<ul class="list-unstyled owner-list">
    @foreach (var package in Model.RecommendedPackages)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Package(package)" title="@package.Id" target="_blank">
                <img class="owner-image" aria-hidden="true" alt="" width="32" height="32"
                    src="@(PackageHelper.ShouldRenderUrl(package.IconUrl) ? package.IconUrl : Url.Absolute("~/Content/gallery/img/default-package-icon.svg"))"
                    @ViewHelpers.ImageFallback(Url.Absolute("~/Content/gallery/img/default-package-icon-256x256.png"))
                    />
            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Package(package)" title="@package.Id" target="_blank">@package.Id</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

resulted in this:

[image]

Since I wanted the anchor text to start on the same line, I used the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445314/4077294) and applied `position: absolute;` to the second anchor:

```
<li style="position: relative;">
    ...
    <a href="@Url.Package(package)" title="@package.Id" target="_blank" style="position: absolute;">@package.Id</a>
</li>
```

resulting in this:

[image]

Then I added word wrap:

```
<li style="position: relative; word-break: break-all;">
```

resulting in this:

[image]

Now this is *still* not satisfactory, because it isn't adjusting the height of the `li` in response to wrapped text, so `margin-bottom` between `li`s isn't working correctly as you can see above. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402618/4077294) for for more info.

On one hand, I need the `position: absolute;` in order to keep the text on the image on the same line. On the other hand, I can't have the `position: absolute;` because it causes the `div` not to take up any space in the document flow, causing the `li` to not expand, causing `margin-bottom` on the `li`s not to work correctly. How do I handle this?

Comment: have you tried : `li {dislay:flex;}` or `li a {display:table-cell;}` or anything else with display or float ? `position` has another purpose.

Comment: `display: table-cell` seemed to do the trick but it prevents `word-wrap` from working.

Comment: Word wrap > do you have some `hyphens: something` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each child element that needs to be horizontally aligned, set the css to:

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
```

If you need to adjust the vertical alignment of the child elements, you can use the `vertical-align` property.

You could also use `display: flex` on the **parent** element as an easier fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first solution didn't work (still on separate lines), your second solution with `display: flex` does but it seems to prevent `word-wrap: break-word` from working. Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Does the line not wrap at all or does it just not break mid-word? You could try setting a max width on the element containing the text.

Comment: It doesn't wrap at all. I would like to set a `max-width` corresponding to the rest of the horizontal space remaining in the `li`, but I don't know how.

Comment: Yep, setting `max-width` makes it work perfectly, but I don't know how to make it match the remaining `li` width without using JS. Hm...

Comment: So, do you want all lines of text (<a> elements) to have a max-width of the shortest line?

Comment: I want all of them to have a max-width equal to the remaining space. i.e. I just tried doing `width: calc(100% - (32px + 5px))` for the second anchor (-32px for the image, -5px for its right margin) and it works, but maybe there's a more maintainable way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: You should just be able to set `flex: 1` on the child element and it will flex to fill the remaining space of parent element (container). Your parent container will need a width.

Comment: That's amazing, your code works :o For some reason `display: flex` seems to be disabling word wrap on my side, though. Nevertheless, I applaud you for your valiant efforts in this question and will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

use display:flex property for those child divs which needs to be on the same line.

[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)