# Prevent line break between html elements

Tags: html, css, scripting

Can anyone help please, need to avoid line break between html elements;
my code is:

```
<td><a href="t"><p d-color="0.80">0.80%</p></a>/<a href="">Map</a></td>
```

the current result is:

```
0.80%
/Map
```

the expected one is:

```
0.80%/Map
```

thanks

Comment: replace `p` with `span` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that paragraphs `<p> </p>` are block level elements. As such they will by default always display in a new line and cause a line break afterwards.

**Option A: Replacing the paragraph with an inline element:**

```html
<d><a href="t"><span d-color="0.80">0.80%</span></a>/<a href="">Map</a></d>
```

**Option B: Making the paragraph inside a link to be inline:**

```css
a p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<d><a href="t"><p d-color="0.80">0.80%</p></a>/<a href="">Map</a></d>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<nobr>`. For example: `<nobr>  Rule 20.9</nobr>` to prevent line break.

Answer (score 0):

You have used paragraph tag <p> which is responsible for line break, because it is a block level element and after a paragraph ends the next text is written from a new line.

So there is a simple solution for this, In the paragraph tag use CSS to inline the element this will bring both the text together.

The code is `<p style="display: inline">`

Use it in your code here:

```
<p d-color="0.80" style="display: inline;">0.80%</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the

tag and considering the answer use `style="display:inline"`

```
<td>
 <a href="t">
  <p style="display:inline" d-color="0.80">0.80%</p>
 </a>
 /<a href="">Map</a>
</td>
```

or you can use  tag instead of

,

```
<td><a href="t"><span d-color="0.80">0.80%</span></a>/<a href="">Map</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this, but I have succesfully made three child DIVs stay on one line using display: inlin-block; position and float. The full description can be found in my answer to [How to force inline divs to stay on same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445164/how-to-force-inline-divs-to-stay-on-same-line/77282976#77282976)